# jQuery select by Href inside specific Div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select a specfic < a > to put a style on it put my code is not working`

```
   var url=window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host+"/"+window.location.pathname;
jQuery('#accordion a[href*="'+url+'"]').css("font-weight", "bold");
```

that code is not working at all and it gives undefind object..so any help here :)

Best Regards
M Hegab

Comment: And you actually use absolute URLs in your links?

Comment: yes .. cause it's complicated site not easy package based site

Comment: If you want a specific anchor, then why not just add an `id` to it and use that?

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.pathname` already starts with a `/`, I'm not *exactly* sure how your setup is, but it should be more like this (without the `/` between host and path):

```
var url=window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host+window.location.pathname;
jQuery('#accordion a[href*="'+url+'"]').css("font-weight", "bold");
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess attribute selectors work independently. This worked for me.

`jQuery("#accordion").find("a[href*='" + url + "']").css("font-weight", "bold");`

If you need to target only the child anchor tags, you can use the `children()` method instead of the `find()` method.

This is the working for me:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Nithesh Chandra</title>
<style>
a.test { color: green; }
</style>
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
</script>
<script language="javascript">
$(function() {
  $('#testDiv').find("a[href*='http://google.com/']").addClass('test');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="testDiv">
  <a href="http://google.com/">Nithesh</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: actually i tried find and it works only if i select (a) otherwise it gives me nothing :( it seems the selection for the href is not working fine here

Comment: try href without the *. I mean if you know the exact url, you can always match it as "Equals" rather than "Contains". Check http://visualjquery.com/ for more options.

Comment: no it's not always that it will be matching exactly.. the parameter may be switch the places from others or the parameters can get deferent values.. that's why i'm using like or contain